# How can I define my own columns in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, xaml

I've got an `AutoGenerateColumns` WPF-DataGrid getting bound in code-behind to LINQ-to-SQL, which works fine.

But when I take off the `AutoGenerateColumns` and define my own columns, it tells me "*The items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.*"

But I'm not binding the `ItemSource` in my XAML so I don't see why it isn't empty. **What do I need to change so that I can define my own columns?**

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestDataGrid566.AppPages.ManageCustomers"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="TheDataGrid" 
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      AlternatingRowBackground="#ddd"
                      CanUserSortColumns="true"
                      PreviewKeyDown="TheDataGrid_PreviewKeyDown"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      RowEditEnding="TheDataGrid_RowEditEnding">

        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact Name" Width="SizeToCells"  
                                    Binding="{Binding ContactName}" 
                                    IsReadOnly="False"/>
    </toolkit:DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

**code-behind:**

```
public partial class ManageCustomers : UserControl
{
    private NorthwindDataContext _db = new NorthwindDataContext();

    public ManageCustomers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        var customers = from c in _db.Customers
                        select c;
        TheDataGrid.ItemsSource = customers.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're trying to put the column directly into the `DataGrid` (therefore it's trying to put the column in the grid's `Items` collection and that explains your error). You need to put it inside the `Columns` collection:

```
<toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="TheDataGrid" 
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          AlternatingRowBackground="#ddd"
                          CanUserSortColumns="true"
                          PreviewKeyDown="TheDataGrid_PreviewKeyDown"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          RowEditEnding="TheDataGrid_RowEditEnding">
    <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>        
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact Name" Width="SizeToCells"  
                                       Binding="{Binding ContactName}" 
                                       IsReadOnly="False"/>
    </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```