# Bind a DataGrid on Certain element of an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, data-binding, mvvm

I am trying to bind a dataGrid with certain element of an ObservableCollection but my problem is when i add a row to my dataGrid all property of the ObservableCollection are displayed

Here a picture of the dataGrid before i add rows :
[image]

Here a picture of the dataGrid with rows added :

[image]

as you can see, columns are added to the datagrid

xaml of the view :

[image]

View Model :

```
  public EntreeDeCommandeViewModel(IBanniereService banniereService
            , IItemsFactureService itemsFactureService
            , IFactureService factureService, INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _banniereService = banniereService;
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _itemsFactureService = itemsFactureService;
            _factureService = factureService;
            RetrieveArgs = new RetrieveArticleFactureArgs();

                AjouterItem = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    List<ItemsFacture> _itFacture = new List<ItemsFacture>();
                    _itFacture.Add(new ItemsFacture() {NombreArticle = RetrieveArgs.NombreArticle
                        , PrixUnitaireArticle = RetrieveArgs.PrixArticle
                        , PrixTotalArticle = (RetrieveArgs.NombreArticle * RetrieveArgs.PrixArticle) });
                    ItemsFactures = new ObservableCollection<ItemsFacture>(_itFacture);
                });
        }

        public RetrieveArticleFactureArgs RetrieveArgs {get; set;}

        private ObservableCollection<ItemsFacture> _itemsFacture;

        public ObservableCollection<ItemsFacture> ItemsFactures
        {
            get
            {
                return _itemsFacture;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_itemsFacture == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                RaisePropertyChanging();
                _itemsFacture = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

The class :

```
public class ItemsFacture : ObservableObject
{
    #region Membre
    private int? _idItemsFacture = null;
    private Facture _facture;
    private Article _article;
    private int? _nombreArticle;
    private double _prixUnitaireArticle;
    private double _prixTotalArticle;
    #endregion

    #region Propriete ItemsFacture
    public virtual int? IdItemsFacture
    {
        get
        {
            return _idItemsFacture;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_idItemsFacture == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging();
            _idItemsFacture = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual Facture Facture
    {
        get
        {
            return _facture;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_facture == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging();
            _facture = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual Article Article
    {
        get
        {
            return _article;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_article == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging();
            _article = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual int? NombreArticle
    {
        get
        {
            return _nombreArticle;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_nombreArticle == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging();
            _nombreArticle = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual double PrixUnitaireArticle
    {
        get
        {
            return _prixUnitaireArticle;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_prixUnitaireArticle == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging();
            _prixUnitaireArticle = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual double PrixTotalArticle
    {
        get
        {
            return _prixTotalArticle;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_prixTotalArticle == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging();
            _prixTotalArticle = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: So what's an issue here? You don't want your binding to work?

Comment: ItemsFactures content 6 properties, I only want 3 of them to be displayed in my dataGrid, but at the moment all properties are displayed.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the AutoGenerateColumns property http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) property to `False` on your dataGrid since you want to customise your columns. By default its true.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   .....
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your [DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `false` otherwise the grid will be generated automatically and your custom defined columns will be ignored.

See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678327/how-can-i-define-my-own-columns-in-a-wpf-datagrid) ;).